# HPUX machinfo equivalent for Linux? or What hardware am I using?

Tags: linux, statistics, hp-ux

In HPUX the command "machinfo" list machine information such as Number of CPUs, Clock speed, Bus speed, processor type, Cache information, total memory, and OS version information.

Is there an equivalent Linux utility?

Comment: You should post this on serverfault.com, when it's live. :)

Comment: If he gets 5 more upvotes, he can try out the serverfault beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of files in `/proc` that contain information about the system, e.g `/proc/cpuinfo`, `/proc/meminfo` etc. See the man page of `proc` for more details.

There are also some utilities which may help you, although some of these may not be installed:

- `dmidecode`
- `x86info`
- `lspci`
- `lsusb`
- `uname`

... and there are probably others, some of which are distribution-dependent.

Comment: uname should probably be added to that list

Comment: Done, the venerable uname is there as well.

Answer (score 2):

*cat /proc/cpuinfo* and *cat /proc/meminfo* are most likely what you are looking for:

CPU information:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model               : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T7700  @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 10
cpu MHz             : 800.000
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id             : 0
cpu cores   : 2
fpu         : yes
fpu_exception       : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp          : yes
flags               : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr lahf_lm ida
bogomips    : 4792.63
clflush size        : 64
cache_alignment     : 64
address sizes       : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model               : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T7700  @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 10
cpu MHz             : 800.000
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id             : 1
cpu cores   : 2
fpu         : yes
fpu_exception       : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp          : yes
flags               : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr lahf_lm ida
bogomips    : 4787.77
clflush size        : 64
cache_alignment     : 64
address sizes       : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Memory information:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:      3977260 kB
MemFree:         26224 kB
Buffers:        141712 kB
Cached:        1190744 kB
SwapCached:         20 kB
Active:        2452144 kB
Inactive:       966032 kB
SwapTotal:     2097144 kB
SwapFree:      2051636 kB
Dirty:           10984 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:     2085712 kB
Mapped:         171640 kB
Slab:           364212 kB
SReclaimable:   323032 kB
SUnreclaim:      41180 kB
PageTables:      29032 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
CommitLimit:   4085772 kB
Committed_AS:  3231676 kB
VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:     20564 kB
VmallocChunk: 34359716859 kB
```